# How to find integration without any sort of modification to the current function?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, indefinite-integrals

I want to integrate a difficult single variable function but I don't want to modify the given function i.e. factorising, rationalizing, etc.
The question is:
$$f(x)= (x^3-4x^2+4x)(x^2-4)^{-1}$$

The answer turns out to be equals to:
$g(x)= (x^2/2)+4\ln(|x-4|)+C$ after factorising the question. But I don't want this!
If you can see, there is something special about the question itself.
At $x=2$ the $f(x)=0/0$. But when we calculate derivative of $g(x)$ we get,
$h(x)= (x^2-4x+4)(x-4)^{-1}$ but $h(x)$ is not equals to $0/0$ at $x=2$...
So I want a $F(X)$ whose derivative will give "exactly" my original given $f(x)$- no factorization, no rationalization, etc...
(You can use u-substitution but be careful my objective shall be achieved)
and I'm well aware that $h(x)$ is equivalent to $g(x)$...
In short, I want a F(X) such that its derivative is exactly equals to my given f(x)- it doesn't matter what techniques you use! You can even use technique other than integration if possible.

Thank you for spending your precious time
Respected Regards,
Swayam Jha

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you want to use things like factoring, rationalizing, etc?

Comment: Strange question... As the derivative of $g$ is $f$ and the antiderivative is unique apart a constant you're done.

Comment: I have specified the reason already! Please read it again carefully. 

Comment: is this a question you made up or is it given to you by someone else?

Comment: The question, I mean the f(x) I have taken from my course book but the objective is my own!

Comment: The simplest way to see that $f(2) =0$ is to use the definition of $f$:  $$f(x)= \frac{x^3-4x^2+4x}{x^2-4x}$$ and simply substitute $x$ by $2$: 

$$f(2)= \frac{2^3-4\cdot 2^2+4\cdot 2}{2^2-4\cdot 2}=  \frac{8-16+8}{4-8}=  \frac{0}{-4}=0$$

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i have mistakenly written that x in denominator. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I personally really dislike these "solve ____ without ____ " type problems.

Comment: @SwayamJha But then... $g(x)= (x^2/2)+4\ln(|x-4|)+C$ is **not** the integral of $f(x)= (x^3-4x^2+4x)(x^2-4)^{-1}$.  Please note that $g'(x)= (x^2-4x+4)(x-4)^{-1}$. It is no longer a matter of multipliying both the numerator and the denominator by $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is that you are treating the indeterminate form $f(2)=0/0$ as a number, while $f(2)$ is well defined, as you can verify by looking at the graph. Applying L'Hopital (or by whatever method you like$^\dagger$), we see that $f(2)=0$. As expected, $g'(2)=0$, so $g'(2)=f(2)$. If you *really* wanted, I suppose you could write

$$ g'(x)=\frac{4}{x-4}+x=\frac{x^2-4x+4}{x-4}$$

Multiply top and bottom by $x-2$

$$ g'(x)=\frac{(x^2-4x+4)(x-2)}{(x-4)(x-2)}=\frac{x^3-6x^2+12x-8}{x^2-6x+8}$$

Which also has the indeterminate form $0/0$ at $x=2$

EDIT: actually, just multiply $g'$ by $1=x/x$ and we recover your original function

$$ g'(x)=\frac{(x^2-4x+4)(x)}{(x-4)(x)}=\frac{x^3-4x^2+4x}{x^2-4x}=f(x)$$

$\dagger$ It is simplest by reversing the last step (dividing by $1=x/x$)

$$f(x)= \frac{x^3-4x^2+4x}{x^2-4x}=\frac{x^2-4x+4}{x-4}$$

Evaluating the right hand side at $x=2$ gives $0/2=0$

Comment: Yeah after your edit I got the answer...... But explain on more time why f(2)=0? By looking at the graph?

Comment: Edited my post with how to find $f(2)$

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is not really possible.

The antiderivative of $\dfrac xx$ is $x$ for all $x\ne0$, the derivative of which is $1$.

You might try to express as

$$x\frac xx,$$ formally giving the derivative

$$\frac xx+x\frac{x-x}{x^2}$$ and it would be arbitrary to say that this is $\dfrac xx$ rather than $\dfrac xx+\dfrac{x-x}x$ or other forms.

---

Also trying $$\frac{x^2}x,$$ we have

$$\frac{2x^2-x^2}{x^2}=\,?$$

Comment: So isn't it possible by any means? I mean there might be a F(x) must exist whose derivative is equals to our original f(x)....?

Comment: @sergeiivanov: your comments have nothing to do with my answer. Please move them.

Comment: No I ain't genius like Ramanujan who can guess. But I got what i wanted. @Sal cleared my query and gave the solution.

Comment: @sergeiivanov: just understand that you commented at the wrong place.